# Laravel 5.8, Tricky subquery with Count(*) in where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel, subquery

I need to write a little tricky subquery in where clause

So, I have a query like this

```
Select * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ...
LEFT JOIN table3 ...
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table where some_condition) = 0;
```

The SQL works fine, but how can I move it into the Laravel?
Yeah, I know that I should use `DB::raw()` but the problem is the subquery returns count. So, for example, the count is 5454. After that, I'm having something like this.

```
->where(5454, '=', 0)
```

and it gives me obvious error message: `Unknown column 5454 ...`

I've tried also to use `AS count` for the subquery but in that case, I'm having another obvious error message: `Syntax error` 0_0

So, any suggestions?

Comment: What is `some_condition` ?

Comment: try `whereRaw("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table where some_condition) = 0")`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , it's just for not writing all query :)

Comment: Well I think you should reveal exactly what that count query has, if you expect an exact answer here.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran , thanks man ! Why it was so simple ? :D
Add an answer please, I'll accept it :)

Comment: I have faced the same issue before. :P happy coding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`whereRaw("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM some_table where some_condition) = 0")`

This will help you.

Comment: Coool.. Happy Coding